# Proving laws of take and drop functions using structural induction on lists

Tags: proof-techniques, induction

I'm trying to prove the following laws using structural induction on (finite) lists:

```
take m (drop n xs) = drop n (take (m + n) xs)
drop m (drop n xs) = drop (m + n) xs
```

for all `m`, `n` and every finite list `xs` (code snippets are in Haskell). I'm not sure how to tackle it though, more specifically: afaik when using induction on intervals, the first induction step is for `m > n` and the second for `m ≤ n`. Now in this case the law must also be valid for all finite lists, does that mean the proof involves prooving all the following?

- case `m > n`: `[]` and `(x:xs)`, and in the latter `m + n > length xs` and `m + n ≤ length xs`
- case `m ≤ n`: `[]` and `(x:xs)`, and in the latter `m + n > length xs` and `m + n ≤ length xs`

If yes I can update my question and show exactly where I'm stuck.

(Please don't post the entire solution, I'd just like to have some pointers. Thanks!)

*UPDATE*

If `[]` denotes the empty list and `(x:xs)` a list with at least one element (`x` is the head of the list and `xs` its tail), possible definitions of `take` and `drop` are:

```
take n [] = []
take 0 xs = []
take n (x:xs) = x : take (n - 1) xs
```

if `n` is greater than `l`, where `l` is the length of the input list, then `take` returns a list of length `l`

```
drop n [] = []
drop 0 xs = xs
drop n (x:xs) = drop (n - 1) xs
```

if `n` is greater than `l`, where `l` is the length of the input list, then `drop` returns the empty list

Comment: The case-split `m>n` and `m<=n` does not look too useful to me, at a first glance. Prove the equations for `xs=[]`, which is trivial. Then, assume that they work on `xs` for all pairs `(n,m)` where either `n<N, m<=M` or `n<=N, m<M`, and prove they must also work on `x:xs` with the pair `(N,M)`. (Check that this is a well-founded ordering)

Comment: Perhaps you could include the definition of `take` and `drop`, for those of us not versed in Haskell.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus very good point thanks, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove the second law by induction on `n`:

- Base case:

`drop m (drop 0 xs) = drop m xs` (definition of `drop`, base case)

`= drop (m + 0) xs` (since `m + 0 = m`)

- Inductive step:

We have to consider two cases: when the input list is empty, and when it's not empty. When it's empty, we have

`drop m (drop n []) = drop m [] = [] = drop (m + n) []` (definition of `drop`, base case)

When the input list is not empty, we have

`drop (m + n) (x:xs) = drop (m + n - 1) xs` (definition of `drop`, inductive case)

`= drop m (drop (n - 1) xs)` (inductive hypothesis)

`= drop m (drop n (x:xs))` (definition of `drop`, inductive case)

I imagine that the first law is not much more difficult. Try to prove it by induction on `n`, and if it doesn't work, try induction on `m`. One of them will probably work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Yeah the other law is trivial once you set up a handy inductive hypothesis. The ones I was originally using were completely bogus and didn't bring me anywhere. One clarification on your solution: you're using induction on `n` in the base case and on `n` and the list in the inductive step. I thought proofs should use inductions on the same (set of) variables (in this case taking `[]` wouldn't have made any difference but I'm more interested in the general case).

Comment: I don't understand your question. My proof is by induction on `n`. The base case and the inductive step comprise the inductive proof. They're two parts of the puzzle. You're correct that there is a part missing, which I will now add.

Comment: Yeah apologies, just re-read my question and I did a bad job at explaining myself. Anyway with the addition of the missing case for `[]` now everything makes sense to me. Thanks again.